# how to skip the first line of a file in python

Tags: python, readline

I need to write a code to read a .txt file, which is a matrix displayed as below, and turn it into an new integer list matrix. However, I want to skip first line of this .txt file without manually deleting the file. I do not know how to do that. 
I have written some code. It is able to display the matrix, but I am unable to get rid of the first line:

```
def display_matrix(a_matrix):
    for row in a_matrix:
        print(row)
    return a_matrix

def numerical_form_of(a_list):
    return [int(a_list[i]) for i in range(len(a_list))]

def get_scoring_matrix():
    scoring_file = open("Scoring Matrix")
    row_num = 0
    while row_num <= NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS:
        content_of_line = scoring_file.readline()
        content_list = content_of_line.split('   ')
        numerical_form = numerical_form_of(content_list[1:])
        scoring_matrix = []
        scoring_matrix.append(numerical_form)
        row_num += 1
        #print(scoring_matrix)
        display_matrix(scoring_matrix)
    # (Complement): row_num = NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS
    return scoring_matrix

get_scoring_matrix()
```

---

```
Scoring Matrix is a .txt file: 
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
4   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
5   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

---

```
The result of my code: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using an automated tool:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_table("Scoring Matrix", delim_whitespace = True)
```

If you insist doing it yourself, change the while loop;

```
while row_num <= NUMBER_OF_FRAGMENTS:
        content_of_line = scoring_file.readline()
        if row_num == 0:
            content_of_line = scoring_file.readline()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! change the while loop works, but why the last line shows a empty list:[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[]

Comment: @ZichenMa likely because there is an extra carriage return at the end of your file, possibly with some spaces on the last line.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

just put a scoring_file.readline() before the while loop.